# Transposing values in data frame based on data in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have the following data frame. How can I form a new data frame/matrix where each row comprises the expectation values of each categorical variable in the ID column and have these values taken in ascending order of time?

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
> df
       ID     Time     Expectation
1         cat  1.1           1
2         dog  1.0           2
3         dog  1.1           3
4  guinea_pig  1.0           7
5         cat  1.0           1
6  guinea_pig  3.8          10
7         cat  0.8           1
8         cat  2.1           1
9         cat  3.6           1
10 guinea_pig  3.0          16
11        dog  0.9           2
12 guinea_pig  2.7          15
13 guinea_pig  4.0          10
14        dog  5.2           6
15        dog  7.2           7
```

For example, the row for dog would read: (2, 2, 3, 6, 7). The one for guinea_pig would be (7, 15, 16, 10, 10), etc. Is it possible to include the categorical data as rownames of the new data frame or matrix?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
library(data.table)

df[order(Time),list(list(Expectation)),.(ID)]

           ID             V1
1:        cat      1,1,1,1,1
2:        dog      2,2,3,6,7
3: guinea_pig  7,15,16,10,10
```

- Sort rows by `Time`
- Group by `ID`
- Get a `list` of `Expectation` column

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df<-fread("
Index ID     Time     Expectation
1         cat  1.1           1
2         dog  1.0           2
3         dog  1.1           3
4  guinea_pig  1.0           7
5         cat  1.0           1
6  guinea_pig  3.8          10
7         cat  0.8           1
8         cat  2.1           1
9         cat  3.6           1
10 guinea_pig  3.0          16
11        dog  0.9           2
12 guinea_pig  2.7          15
13 guinea_pig  4.0          10
14        dog  5.2           6
15        dog  7.2           7")

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarise(Expectation_All =paste(Expectation, collapse = ","))
# ID         Expectation_All
# <chr>      <chr>          
#   1 cat        1,1,1,1,1      
# 2 dog        2,3,2,6,7      
# 3 guinea_pig 7,10,16,15,10
```

Comment: the answer is incorrect. check values for dog, you need to sort them first

Comment: I don't know whether this is what the OP wants, but pasting all values together will make it difficult to extract elements and do other operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, using `aggregate` + `order`, i.e.,

```
aggregate(Expectation~ID,df[order(df$ID,df$Time),],FUN = list)
```

such that

```
          ID       Expectation
1        cat     1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2        dog     2, 2, 3, 6, 7
3 guinea_pig 7, 15, 16, 10, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` edition:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(var = list(Expectation[order(Time)]))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   ID         var      
#   <chr>      <list>   
# 1 cat        <int [5]>
# 2 dog        <int [5]>
# 3 guinea_pig <int [5]>
```

To see the inner values, add `%>% print.data.frame`:

```
#           ID               var
# 1        cat     1, 1, 1, 1, 1
# 2        dog     2, 2, 3, 6, 7
# 3 guinea_pig 7, 15, 16, 10, 10
```